# Form submit not working in onchange method

Tags: jquery

I submit my form when the `onchange` event of my drop down is fired using jQuery.

The first time it works, but the second time the `onchange` event is not fired. It does not even enter into the jQuery script. How can I resolve this issue? And how do I load jQuery in the `onload` event?
My Jquery Code:

```
 $('#statusId').bind('change',function() { 
    alert($(this).val());
    $('#statusHiddenId').val($(this).val());
    $('#layoutFormID').attr('method', 'POST'); 
    $('#layoutFormID').attr('action', '/sample');
    $('#layoutFormID').submit();
});
```

HTML CODE:

```
select(name='status',rel = "external", id='statusId', data-theme='a', data-icon='gear', data-native-menu="false")
     option(value='0') All Status
     option(value='1') New
     option(value='2') Verified
     option(value='3') KYC Completed
     option(value='4') Loan Sanctioned
     option(value='5') Loan Disbursed
     option(value='6') Closed
     option(value='7') Archive
```

Comment: The onchange event handler is becoming detached from its DOM element, probably due to element replacement, but need to see code in order to fix it.

Comment: is the html code pseudocode or is it a scripting language and if so what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

put this code inside javascript function and call it each time by onchange.

```
function MyFunction()
{
    $('#statusHiddenId').val($(this).val());
    $('#layoutFormID').attr('method', 'POST'); 
    $('#layoutFormID').attr('action', '/sample');
    $('#layoutFormID').submit();
}
```

**onchange = MyFunction();**

```
specify onchange function in select box.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant "document load" when you say `onload`, then the code is:

```
$(function(){

    // your code here

});
```

If your script is replacing form content, you need to bind your handler farther up the chain, like so:

*(assuming you had a container element with the id of "container" that **does not** get replaced)*

```
$('#container').on('change', '#statusId', function(event) {

    // your code here

});
```

This assumes you're using jQuery 1.7 or greater.